# Clip to bounds of a different UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, cliptobounds

I have two `UIImageView`s, `imageView1` and `imageView2`. I've set

```
self.imageView1.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

but I was wondering if it is possible to set `imageView1` to `clipToBounds` of `imageView2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not easily. The "right" way to do this would be to use a clipping path on the `imageView1`'s layer. However, you can get the same effect much more easily as follows.

Put `imageView1` centered inside a container `UIView`, and turn that view's `clipsToBounds` on. Then:

- If you're using Auto Layout, constrain the container view's size to be equal to the size of `imageView2`.
- If you're not using Auto Layout, set the bounds of the container view to the size of `imageView2` whenever you calculate layout.